How to automatically populate documentation with %(before_notes)s and %(after_notes)s?
I have written a module for a research project that implements some probability distributions as subclasses of Scipy's rv_continuous class. Now I would like to create some documentation for my module and I would like that documentation to be consistent with Scipy's. I see that Scipy's probability distribution docstrings (e.g. the one for scipy.stats.uniform here) use a dictionary to insert boiler-plate text and (I think) to generate examples automatically: %(before_notes)s, %(example)s, and %(after_notes)s.
As far as I can tell this dictionary is kept in scipy.stats._distn_infrastructure.py but I can't see how to use it. How do I go about this? I am using Sphinx, of course.

The logic for doing that is here.
Essentially, the way that this works is that whenever a instance of this class is instantiated, it accesses its own docstring with self.__doc__, manipulates the string, then alters its docstring by assigning back to self.__doc__. The scipy._lib.doccer.docformat function is responsible for performing the string manipulation.
To create the documentation, whenever scipy.stats is imported, one of these classes is instantiated and assigned to scipy.stats.uniform. The documentation that you see is technically the documentation of an instance, not a class, which you can notice on the documentation page here:

Since uniform is included in the module's __all__, but uniform_gen is not, Sphinx generates a documentation page for this instance but not the class.
As far as I know, if you inherit from rv_continuous, and instantiate your class, you'll get this functionality by default.

Hi Nick. Thank you very much! So how would I get that working for my own code? Presumably I need to alter my conf.py and import the relevant modules before I build the documentation with Sphinx?
